# New column with nested if else based on two columns, ignoring NA if present in only one other column

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset containing two variables, var1 and var2. Some cases have a value in var1 and some in var2. Cases with a value in var1 are NA in var2 and vice versa. I would like to combine these variables into one with the value 1 or 0. The new variable should take on the value of 1 if var1 OR var2 has a value of 1, the value of 0 if var1 or var2 has a value of 0 and NA only if both var1 and var2 is NA.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to get R to ignore NA in var1 or var2 if there is a value in the other, and only return NA is NA are present in BOTH variables.

I have tried the following solutions:

First attempt:

```
df$new_var<-ifelse(df$var1==1|df$var2==1,1,
                    ifelse(df$var1<1|df$var2<1,0,
                        ifelse(is.na(df$var1)&df$var2<1,0,0
                           ifelse(is.na(df$var2)&df$var1<1,0,0))))
```

Second attempt:

```
df$new_var<-ifelse(df$var1==1|df$var2==1,1,
                    ifelse(df$var1==0|df$var2==0,0,NA))
```

Third attempt:

```
df$new_var<-ifelse(df$var1==1|df$var2==1,1,
                    ifelse(df$var1==0|df$var2==0,0,NA))
```

All returns a variable with 1 and NAs and no 0.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: what if the values are 1 and 0 ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper - OP specified that only one of the variables can have a value other than NA - "cases with a value in var1 are NA in var2 and vice versa" - so it's actually much simpler a problem than it appears :)

Comment: For future reference, a sample of data and expected output would have been really helpful in illustrating your goal.

Comment: Yes, I see that, and will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I know of to do this is with `dplyr::coalesce`:

```r
dplyr::coalesce(c(1,0,0,NA), c(1, NA, 1, 1))
#> [1] 1 0 0 1
```

Why bother writing the expression to do it if someone has done it for you? ;)

Comment: this doesn't work for the third value as the second array is 1 and should return 1 not 0

Comment: It took me a while to understand the parameters of the question, but I believe "Cases with a value in var1 are NA in var2 and vice versa" is meant to mean `IF var1 is NA, then var2 is not`, and `IF var2 is NA, then var1 is not`.  In otherwords, exactly one of each pair is `NA`.  That was hard to see without expected input and output.  Both of these solutions work, but the `pmax` solution is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pmax`

```
df <- expand.grid(c(1, 0, NA), c(1, 0, NA))
df$new_var <- pmax(df$Var1, df$Var2, na.rm = TRUE)

> df
  Var1 Var2 new_var
1    1    1       1
2    0    1       1
3   NA    1       1
4    1    0       1
5    0    0       0
6   NA    0       0
7    1   NA       1
8    0   NA       0
9   NA   NA      NA
```